# Access Control Allow Headers not allowing contents of an iframe to load

Tags: php, iframe, access-control, x-frame-options

I have two php pages in the same directory. These are `edit_page.php` and `page.php`.

`edit_page.php` has a wysiwyg editor where I can edit the contents of another page through an iframe. the source for the iframe is `page.php` with a query `?page_id=XXX`.

When I go to  `page.php?page_id=XXX` I can see the following headers:

[image]

However when I go to `edit_page.php?page_id=XXX` I see the following errors in the console:

[image]

I tried putting the headers in the page sending the request just for the laugh even though I know that it is making the request and not sending the response header.... worth a try :P

[image]

The headers I'm sending are:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type");
header("X-Frame-Options: *");
```

I'm a bit stuck with this one I've never come across this kind of issue before. If anyone can point me in the right direction that would be greatly appreciated.

Also if anyone can explain why this is happening in the first place that would be great. My understanding was that this would happen with pages from a cross origin e.g. loading content from an external source not on the same domain. But obviously these two files are not only on the same domain but in the same directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok now I feel stupid....

I had:

```
<iframe name="richTextField" id="wysiwyg" src="page?page_id=1"></iframe>
```

Instead of:

```
<iframe name="richTextField" id="wysiwyg" src="page.php?page_id=1"></iframe>
```

Going brain dead I think

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that `https://lifting365.com/EUR/beta/admin/page/` has set `X-Frame-Options: sameorigin`.

You appear to be trying to set `X-Frame-Options: *` (which isn't a valid value for the header, try [reading the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) to see what values are allowed) on `http://lifting365.com/something/edit_page?page_id=1`.

So the first problem is that **you are setting the headers on the wrong page**.

It is the page you want to display *in the frame* that needs to grant permission. The page with the `<iframe>` element in it doesn't need to grant itself permission to include an iframe!

---

Your second problem is that your basic approach to this is wrong.

You shouldn't be trying to lower security restrictions so a page from `https://lifting365.com` can be displayed on http://lifting365.com`. You should be moving **all** the pages to HTTPS.

This would:

- Make them more secure and trustworthy
- Put them on the same origin (eliminating the problem you are asking about)

---

> Also if anyone can explain why this is happening in the first place that would be great.

One of the factors needed to make two origins be the same is a shared URL scheme. `http:` and `https:` are different.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I got it sorted. Like I said, `I tried putting the headers in the page sending the request just for the laugh even though I know that it is making the request and not sending the response header.... worth a try :P` didn't think it would actually work. Also I set `X-Frame-Options: ` to anything I could think of trying to get this to work... Turns out it was just the most stupid mistake I made